# python decorator for function argument preprocessing

Tags: python, decorator

my original problem is I need to strip a string and then split by a operator.

```
s = " a & b | c & d "
l = map(lambda x : map(lambda x:x.strip() , x.strip().split('&')), s.strip().split('|'))
```

this is too cumbersome for people to read, so I am thinking to use decorator to do this strip() preprocessing.

here is my current solution, but it's not working!

### Update:

```
query_AND =lambda wl:  '.*'+'.*'.join(wl)+'.*'

def d_query_AND(query_split):
    def d_query_AND_f(query_split):
        return query_AND(query_split)
        #return query_spli
    return d_query_AND_f


@d_query_AND
def query_split(p):
    return [v for v in p.split('&')]


print query_split("asd & asdsa & sadsa")
```

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail why you think a decorator is the right tool for this?

Comment: "it's not working" is not a problem description. What output are you getting? Is there an error?

Comment: Using a list comprehension would be far more readable than your `map()` solution: `[v.strip() for p in s.split('|') for v in p.split('&')]` (you only need to strip the resulting values once).

Comment: And it's *stripped*, not striped. :-) The latter means 'with alternating bands of colour'.

Comment: Generally the nested function (`striped`) doesn't get passed the function `f` as an argument.  It gets that information from the closure.

Comment: This will never work. Decorator functions are called when the decorated function is defined, not when it is called. The never get to see the run time arguments to the function. Also, at least you need to call the `ff` function with two arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , this is good solution, but not really I am asking , is there a way to use decorator to preprocess the v with strip() ?

Comment: @Jerry, your code doesn't contain any kind of loop. Why did you expect it would work?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just realized your solution give a flat list, which is not what I need, my solution give a list of list!

Comment: @JerryGao: The point still stands: only strip the remaining elements. You can create a list of lists with a list comprehension too: `[[v.strip() for v in p.split('&')] for p in s.split('|')]`

Comment: @MartijnPieters this is ok, thank you! but I guess decorator does not work in this kind of case...

Comment: @JerryGao: The problem with your decorators are many; it may well work with a decorator but it isn't clear to me what you wanted to achieve with it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters please see the updated code, does it show the need for decorator better?

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I don't fully understand why you need a decorator.

One relatively easy way to tokenize these expressions is by using a regex:

```
In [12]: re.findall(r'[^|&\s]+|&|[|]', ' a & b | c & d ')
Out[12]: ['a', '&', 'b', '|', 'c', '&', 'd']

In [13]: re.findall(r'[^|&\s]+|&|[|]', 'asdasd&sdasd| asdsa & asdsda')
Out[13]: ['asdasd', '&', 'sdasd', '|', 'asdsa', '&', 'asdsda']
```

The regex consists of three components OR-ed together:

- `[^|&\s]+` matches a sequence of characters other than `&`, `|` and whitespace.
- `&` matches `&`.
- `[|]` matches `|`.

If you don't need to capture the operators, the regex can be simplified to `r'[^|&\s]+'`.

**edit**: If you don't want to split on the spaces, as you imply in the comments, the following should work:

```
In [18]: map(string.strip, re.findall(r'[^|&]+|&|[|]', 'asdasd&sd  asd| asdsa & asdsda'))
Out[18]: ['asdasd', '&', 'sd  asd', '|', 'asdsa', '&', 'asdsda']
```

Comment: this method does not work with  A & B C | D which should I need to get [['A', 'B C'], ['D']]

Comment: thank you for the edit! this is useful, but in my case I need to get a list of list which does not have '&' , '|' in it, the reason is I need to use ".*".join() to form a search query, please see the updated code in my question.